# Angular - Directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular. Not sure why directive is not working below. Searched some articles. Nothing helps

```
angular.module('oneApp', []).controller('OneAppController', function($scope){
    //Some Logic
}).directive('dvReplaceText', ['$interval', '$compile', function($interval, $compile) {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch(scope.data, function(value) {
                element.html(value);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

**HTML**:

```
<body ng-app="oneApp">
    <div ng-controller="OneAppController">
        <input class="input-data-box" ng-model="data" dv-replace-text=""/>
    </div>
</body>
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/pingskp/LzLe71ft/)

Comment: aside from you not having the Fiddle set up right (change to No Wrap - in <head>)... What is this supposed to do? you have the directive assigned to an `<input>` element, and then are trying to change the `html` of the element, but `<input>` doesn't have an `html` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be:

```
scope.$watch('data', function(value) {
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should change $watch like this :

```
scope.$watch('data', function(value) {
                element.html(value);
                console.log(value);
            });
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/vikashvverma/LzLe71ft/6/

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```js
angular.module('oneApp', []).controller('OneAppController', function($scope){
 
    //Some Logic
}).directive('dvReplaceText', ['$interval', '$compile', function($interval, $compile) {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch("data", function(value) {
                //element.value(value);
              console.log(value);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="oneApp">
    <div ng-controller="OneAppController">
        <input class="input-data-box" ng-model="data" dv-replace-text=""/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('OneAppController', function($scope){
        //Some Logic
    console.log("data loaded");
    });


app.directive('dvReplaceText', function() {
      return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                scope.$watch(scope.data, function(value) {
                    element.html(value);
                });
            }
        }
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="OneAppController">
    <input class="input-data-box" ng-model="data" dv-replace-text/>
</div>
```

Here is the working model [JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/RmDuw/323/)